# Изменение дизайна тулбара приложения

Tags: c#, wpf

Необходимо реализовать темный тулбар, подскажите, как это сделать?

Пример, Visual Studio: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы можете сделать это либо путем обработки события BackColorChanged, либо переопределения защищенного метода OnBackColorChanged в вашем классе основной формы

Comment: А в чём конкретно проблема? Вы не знаете, как создать тулбар, или не можете покрасить фон вашего тулбара в чёрный цвет?

Comment: @VladD перекраска

Comment: @SKProCH: Тогда покажите код, который рисует ваш тулбар.

Comment: @VladD я вас, наверное, сначала не правильно понял. Мне нужно сменить фон у тулбара, который предоставляется стандартно (в котором есть название, и кнопки "закрыть", "свернуть"), мне не нужно делать отдельный тулбар.

Comment: Хм. Хороший вопрос. Традиционно такая кастомизация делается при помощи `WindowChrome`, но у меня не получилось при этом получить одновременно и цвет фона, и стандартные кнопки «свернуть/развернуть/закрыть». Вот вопросы по теме: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34495991/276994, https://stackoverflow.com/q/44190041/276994. Если кнопки вы хотите тоже рисовать сами, тогда всё проще.

Comment: @VladD хорошо, буду гуглить в этом направлении, интересно, что получится. А пока ждал ответа придумал реализацию нужных мне кнопок, так что вопрос можно считать закрытым